# How to re-register a dynamically loaded angular templates' directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

I have a directive which loads a template with a bunch on input fields. One of which is the jQuery/Bootstrap datepicker.

```
<my-directive-buttons></my-directive-buttons>
```

When a user selects/clicks on the datepicker field, the calendar is displayed. I have also attached an `ng-click` to the input field:

```
<div class='col-sm-6'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group datepick'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-click="addCalendarFooter()"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On click, the calender is displayed and `$scope.addCalendarFooter` is called:

```
app.directive('myDrectiveButtons', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {

        },
        templateUrl: 'controls/input-fields.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        },
        controller: function($scope) {


            $scope.addCalendarFooter = function() {
                $('#datepicker').append($('<div></div>').load('myDir/calendar/customFooter.html'));
            }

        }
    }
});
```

I am successful in appending the contents of `customFooter.html` to the calendar, however, within `customFooter.html` are further `ng-clicks`, which when pressed, are not being called. E.g

customFooter.html

```
<div>
    <button ng-click="controlClick()">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Yet, if i move this button out of `customFooter.html` and in to `input-field.html`, to test the button logic is correct, the click is called.

I have tried `$scope.$apply` and `$scope.digest` after the `.append`, however i get a 'digest already in progress error'

UPDATE:

Based on comments, below, have tried to remove jQuery and use an 'angular way'

```
$scope.addCalendarFooter = function() {

    var html = "<div ng-include src=\"myDir/calendar/customFooter.html\"><\div>";


    var myEl = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('datepicker');

    myEl.html(html);

     $compile(myEl)($scope)

}
```

The above inserts my .html template via the ng-include however is it replacing the contents of the datepicker rather than inserting at the bottom of it. Tried .append but that didn't worth either.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. `$('#datepicker').append($('<div></div>').load('myDir/calendar/customFooter.html'));` - this is a problem. Learn how to do it Angular way. You can fix it of course, but this pretty bad practice.

Comment: @dfsq - thanks for the advice. Can you provide some guidance on 'the angular way'?

Comment: You should use ngIf (with ngInclude inside to lazy load template). Then UI Bootstrap datepicker instead of jQuery plugin.

Comment: @dfsq - thanks for that, made some progress with ng-include. See UPDATE above,".

Comment: Your progress is still really bad. It's not Angular way. Maybe I need to add the answer.

Comment: @dfsq that would be useful. I'm keen to learn and improve skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from your UPDATE:

> The above inserts my .html template via the ng-include however is it replacing the contents of the datepicker rather than inserting at the bottom of it. Tried .append but that didn't worth either.

The aforementioned issue is due to using `.html()` method which inserts HTML to a DOM node and *overwrites* any existing content of the selected node:

```
 var html = "<div ng-include src=\"myDir/calendar/customFooter.html\"><\div>";
 var myEl = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('datepicker');  
 myEl.html(html); // <== here
 $compile(myEl)($scope)
```

What you are doing with the above logic is that you first select the `.datePicker` element, then you *replace* its inner HTML with the `.html()` method.

As a workaround, you could have used `.append()` method instead.

**NOTE:** `angular.element()` is Angular's wrapper for an element just as in `jQuery` you had `$()`. Therefore, using `document.getElementByClassName()` method is redundant in your case.

---

Although the above workaround might solve your problem, but it is better to stick to a cleaner and concise approach which AngularJS may offer.

## *Angularesque* Approach

You don't need to load a template partial by *programmatically* adding/appending the template in a controller function - at least in Angular's way. This way you might end up not binding the angular directive(s) within the dynamically added HTML correctly with a scope.

Instead, just include the partial within the original directive template (with `ng-include`) and use `ngIf` or `ngShow` to display it when the button is clicked.

Therefore, assuming that you've the footer template (`customFooter.html`) in the original directive template, you can achieve the expected result as in the following:

#### Directive Template

```
<div class='col-sm-6'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group datepick'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-click="addCalendarFooter()"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-include="myDir/calendar/customFooter.html" ng-if="isCalenderFooterAdded"></div>
```

#### Directive Controller

```
controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.addCalendarFooter = function() {
         $scope.isCalendarFooterAdded = true;
         // or use this if you want to toggle it
         // $scope.isCalendarFooterAdded = !$scope.isCalendarFooterAdded ? true: false;
    }
}
```

#### [***Plunkr***](https://plnkr.co/edit/vzCksgmxdEu23t5o3bPH?p=preview) mimicking a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically loading the footer manually and bypassing angular completely. Angular doesn't see that you're loading the html and so doesn't compile the html template and bind directives, including ng-click, at all.

You can use ng-include directive that loads the specified template, instead of making a custom one yourself. Or if your directive needs other functionality, just have the ng-include in the directive template itself.

Answer (score 0):

What if you include your footer in your template initially but hide it with ng-if / ng-show. Then the function would only change a flag and show the previously hidden footer.

Comment: I'm using the Bootstrap date picker so I don't have access to it initially otherwise I would use no-include. The datepicker DOM markup is added the html on click.

Comment: See UPDATE with ng-include

Answer (score 0):

You said that your problem is the fact that after calling `$scope.$apply` or `$scope.digest` you get the `$digest already in progress` error.

A clever way to bypass this is using [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync). One of  its biggest advantages is that it knows if it should perform an extra digest cycle of not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ng-include don't forget the singlequotes at the begining and end of the path.

Angular doc about ng-include: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

> make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g. src="'myPartialTemplate.html'"

it should be:
`var html = "<ng-include src=\"'myDir/calendar/customFooter.html'\"><\ng-include>";`

or:
`var html = "<div ng-include=\"'myDir/calendar/customFooter.html'\"><\div>";`

but not:
`var html = "<div ng-include src=\"myDir/calendar/customFooter.html\"><\div>";`